# Is there a way to detect an alphanumeric Unicode symbol?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode

I have a Unicode string consisting of letters, digits and punctuation marks. Ho can I detect characters that are digits and letters (not necessarily ASCII) with a C++ standard library or Win32 API?

Comment: Did my post provide you with the necessary information?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**iswdigit()**, **iswalpha()** and **iswalnum()** are the functions you are looking for.

Cheers !

Comment: Don't these just check the same thing as isdigit(), isalpha(), isalnum()? The original post seems to be asking to detect non-Latin digits and letters.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is the Win32 API call [GetStringTypeW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318119(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the ICU library.  It has all that Unicode data, as well as a decent Unicode string class for C++.

Answer (score 2):

[This Microsoft documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28VS.71%29.aspx) describes "Unicode character classes" in regular expressions, which sounds highly relevant. I think the answer is in the .Net domain, and not pure Win32 C++, but perhaps you can dig something up.

Comment: Link leads to Regex syntax reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Declare Function GetStringTypeW Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal InfoType As Long, Text As Byte, ByVal Length As Long, Types As Integer) As Long
...
Dim S As String, B() As Byte, C() As Integer, L as Long
L = Len(S)
ReDim C(1 To L)
B = S
If GetStringTypeW(1, B(0), L, C(1)) Then
    'Character classes are in C.
Else
    'Something went wrong. Deal with it or call Err.Raise.
End If
```